# How is it true that $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am having doubts this is true.
So elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$has the form $p+qi+r\sqrt{3}$ for some rational $p,q,r$.

This means that I must be able to express $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ in the form of $p+qi+r\sqrt{3}$. Well, how's that going to happen for some $p,q,r$? I don't think it's possible and therefore $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$.

ANSWER I AM LOOKING FOR: Proof that  $-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$

can someone explicitly prove me wrong please?

Comment: It's not the splitting field for $x^3-1$, that has degree $2$, and your field has degree $4$.

Nonetheless, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3, i)\supseteq \Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$ where the latter is the splitting field in question.

Also, you are missing a basis element, you only have 3 things, $p,q,r$, but the vector space has dimension $4$, so you are missing the vital basis element $i\sqrt 3$ which makes it easy to solve.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase the question now to pinpoint my question as narrow as possible

Comment: You've made the classic error and assumed adjoining two elements $a$ and $b$ makes the field look like $p+qa+rb$. This is just false in general. You've let the notation fool you. $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ does **not** necessarily mean the result is a three-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrect about what elements of the field look like. The set of the form you specified isn't a field, because $i\sqrt{3}$ is not in it, making it not closed under multiplication. This is a common mistake. In fact you have that all elements are of the form $$a+bi+c\sqrt{3}+di\sqrt{3}$$

The way to do this in general for $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is to write out $\sum a_i \alpha^j\beta^k$ where $i=j+k$ and then figure out which are redundant via linear dependence. The general general case is similar.

For an explicit proof: by closure $i\sqrt{3}$ is in the field. But every rational multiple of a number in the field is, so $\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is in the field. By closure under addition, $-\frac{1}{2}$ plus $\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is in the field

Comment: thanks, Im having so much trouble getting rings, fields, integral domains and mountains of definitions in my brain. Is a ring IN an field or a field IN a ring? Since field has multiplication being Abelian while ring only asks to be a monoid, I thought a ring is IN a field, so smaller. I'm so confused with this.

Comment: All fields are rings, so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Okay. so fields $\subseteq$ rings then.

Comment: Yes. A field is a ring with multiplicative inverses for every element.

Comment: @Melba1993: In mathematics, $\mathbb N$ is typically used to describe the set of natural numbers. Using this definition, $\mathbb N$ is not a ring (and therefore also not a field).

Answer (score 5):

From the very first line:

> I am having doubts this is true.
>   So elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$has the form $p+qi+r\sqrt{3}$ for some rational $p,q,r$.

Why do you say that? It's not true. As you noticed yourself, $i \sqrt{3}$ becomes a problem if you assume all elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$ are of this form. But $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$ is a ring, and so the product of two elements should always be in the ring...

In general, $\mathbb{Q}(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is the set of all *polynomials* of the type:
$$\sum_{k_1, \dots, k_n} x_{k_1, \dots, k_n} a_1^{k_1} \dots a_n^{k_n}.$$
A polynomial may have degrees greater than $1$. As it turns out, with early examples of ring extensions like $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, you can get away with polynomials of degree only $1$. But that's because $i^2 = -1$ and $\sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ are both in $\mathbb{Q}$, and so you don't find anything new when you look at polynomials of higher degree. In general, you must, though: look at $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$, for example.

---

Now for a proof that $-1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$: there are several ways of defining $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$, but one way is to consider the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$, $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$. Then since $1/2$, $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$, so is the product $\sqrt{3} \cdot 1/2 \cdot i$, and finally the sum $-1/2 + i \sqrt{3}/2$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 0):

For any field, F, if a,b are in F, then ab is in F. That continues to hold for field extenstions. If you are looking at Q(a,b) then most certainly ab is in Q(a,b) (and a+b, a-b, a/b, etc.)